Add a textbox for each row in rshiny data table displayed in dashboard
Trying to add  textbox in each row of a data table displayed shiny dashboard similar to buttons as example below. Each line will have unique value tied similar to what is obtained from the button. I am not able to track the text inputed similar to button. The example code below is taken from
Handle actionButtons in DataTable.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
        textOutput('myText')
    ),
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
        myValue <- reactiveValues(employee = '')
        
        shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
            inputs <- character(len)
            for (i in seq_len(len)) {
                inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
            }
            inputs
        }
        
        df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
            Name = c('Dilbert', 'Alice', 'Wally', 'Ashok', 'Dogbert'),
            Motivation = c(62, 73, 3, 99, 52),
            Actions = shinyInput(actionButton, 5, 'button_', label = "Fire", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
            TextInput = shinyInput(textInput, 5, 'text_', label = "Write" ),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            row.names = 1:5
        ))
        
        
        output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
            df$data, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
        )
        
        observeEvent(input$select_button, {
            selectedRow <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
            myValue$employee <<- paste('click on ',df$data[selectedRow,1])
        })
        
        output$myText <- renderText({
            myValue$employee
        })
    }
)


You could use reactable and reactable.extra see reactable.extra documentation for custom input
Created an example code snippet using your example here;
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(reactable.extras)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    reactable.extras::reactable_extras_dependency(),
    reactableOutput("react"),
    hr(),
    textOutput("button_text"),
    textOutput("text")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$react <- renderReactable({
      # preparing the test data
      df <- data.frame(
        Name = c('Dilbert', 'Alice', 'Wally', 'Ashok', 'Dogbert'),
        Motivation = c(62, 73, 3, 99, 52),
        Actions = c('Fire'),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        Text = c(""),
        row.names = 1:5
      )
      reactable(
        df,
        columns = list(
          Actions = colDef(
            cell = button_extra("button", class = "button-extra")
          ),
          Text = colDef(
            cell = text_extra(
              "text"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    })
    output$button_text <- renderText({
      req(input$button)
      values <- input$button
      paste0(
        "Button: ",
          paste0("{", paste0(names(values), " : ", unlist(values), 
          collapse = ", "), "}")
      )
    })

    output$text <- renderText({
      req(input$text)
      values <- input$text
      paste0(
        "Dropdown: ",
          paste0("{", paste0(names(values), " : ", unlist(values), 
          collapse = ", "), "}")
      )
    })
  }
)


Thanks for the solution. I get the error "Warning: Error in string_list: could not find function "string_list" when I input the values...maybe I am missing some thing.

Sorry about that, should be fixed now

Thanks for your input. The code is working as expected. Sorry for delay in responding.
